# lambda で logger を利用するには？

Tags: python, aws, aws-lambda

lambda 上で、 logger の動作を検証するために、以下のスクリプトを用意しました。

```
import logging

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.debug('test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lambda_handler(None, None)
```

これをコマンドラインから実行した場合には、以下のように、正しくログが出力されます。

```
$ python lambda_function.py
DEBUG:root:test
```

しかし、これを lambda 上で実行した場合には、ロガーの表示は行われません。

#### 質問:

- lambda 上で、 logger の debug/info 出力をするには、どうしたらよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

CloudWatch Logs に記録されていませんでしょうか？

[ログ記録 (Python)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html)
[AWS Lambda の Amazon CloudWatch ログへのアクセス](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html)